# Kivy: Button binding in .py file

Tags: button, binding, kivy

Is it possible to pass arguments (??argument??) to a method in a python file?
Example:

```
class MyLayout(GridLayout): 
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(**kwrgs)
        self.button = Button(text= "b1")
        self.button.on_press = self.delete(??argument??) # <----- HERE

    def delete(self,argument):
        self.remove_widget(argument)
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [partial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) method:

```
self.button.on_press = partial(self.delete, argument)
```